# Is my alternate earth possible?

Tags: science-based, biology, alternate-earth

You see, my alternate earth has lots of monstrous, uncivilized beasts like the Cipactlis and Timberwolves. My planet was formed long ago duel to molecules becoming these beasts like normal Earth. This earth is covered mostly by a lush, green, jungle, with oceans surrounding it, the ocean home to monsters like sea serpents. The climate is sunny most of the time, with occasional rainfall, and the night is as long as the normal Earth's night. Given these characteristics, could my planet exist?

Comment: "duel to molecules becoming these beasts like normal earth" spelling mistakes aside, thats just how everything works, molecules form it

Comment: If I'm following, you want an Earth filled with creatures like dinosaurs. If they existed once in one place, they can exist somewhere else under similar conditions. Timberwolves would not be well adapted to a jungle environment, but if you want them, remember a planet is a big place and multiple biomes allow numerous species. If special starting particles leading to 'monsters' are present, it's even easier. Am I understanding the question correctly?

Comment: DWKraus, you're perfectly understanding the question.

Comment: Since when are [timber wolves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwestern_wolf) considered *monsters*? This is offending to all the timber wolves of the world. (And why isn't the Earth in the [Cretaceous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous) period a good enough example for this question?)

Comment: Um, you have a good point, but the Timberwolves in the alternate Earth are called Timberwolves because they use timber as armor.

Comment: You have not provided enough astrological, geological, or biological information to give you an objective answer to "can my planet exist?" I'm not convinced any question of the form "can X exist?" can be meaningfully answered. What specific worldbuilding problem are you asking us to help with? Because validating the veracity of your project is outside the scope and purpose of this site with the exception of the [tag:reality-check] tag, which has *very specific rules* that are not met by this question.

Comment: Everyone asking about Timberwolves needs to understand that the [OP has a specific concept of a "timberwolf" that has nothing to do with it's terrestrial counterpart](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/192023/40609). They're made up of twigs and sticks. They are literally wolves made out of timber.

Answer (score 1):

#### I see no reason why it shouldn't.

Everything you've described is plausible, comparable things exist or have existed on Earth historically, and nothing there is mutually exclusive with each other.

Comment: ''Sunny most of time'' means that in the daytime, it's sunny.

Answer (score 1):

> This earth is covered mostly by a lush, green, jungle, with oceans surrounding it, the ocean home to monsters like sea serpents.

That is like the jurassic period in our world, so yes, its quite realistic. But remember that jungles usually need a lot of water in the form of rainfall, so the rainfall should probable be more often than occasional